# How do I change my TFS identity?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, credentials

When I was first getting set up in TFS, my company misspelled my username. They since changed it to the correct spelling, but that change was apparently not reflected in TFS. When I try to check in changes, I get this error:

[image]

Is there a way I can change my TFS identity to the one with the correct spelling so I can check stuff in from my machine? Our TFS administrator has looked at it and isn't sure how to fix it.

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

EDIT: I have tried removing and re-mapping my workspace, no luck.

Also, I can check in files in Visual Studio 2010, but it gives me the error in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Does your company use AD and domain log-ins? Are you logging in with the correct username? Is your new username included in the AD group for TFS?

Comment: It's possibly a workspace issue. Are you trying to checkin changes that you made under your old account? Did you map a new workspace under your new account to the same location as the workspace for your old account?

Comment: @Alicia: We use domain log-ins. I am logging in to Windows with the correct username. The new username is included in TFS, as I have been able to successfully check in changes before. It just stopped working for some reason.

Comment: @ppejovic: I am not trying to check in changes I made under my old account.

Comment: It should update automatically if that is an AD account (DEV\yourname), at least is does in TFS 2010. We have a user who recently shortened her name via AD and it updated automatically. Perhaps your network guy needs to sync controllers or something in AD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fellow employee fixed it. Here's what he did:

Removed all workspaces, deleted all files, cleared the credential manager, disconnected from TFS, deleted the TFS connection, closed VS, opened VS, created a new connection to TFS, re-downloaded all files.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the credeantial manager of windows and change the username for the respective TFS intance.

Comment: I added a generic credential. No luck.

Comment: Did you delete the whole entry for your TFS? If you do the next time you connect to the TFS it will prompt again for credentials. Then type in the right ones and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2012

Click on your Workspace dropdown

Select Workspaces

Highlight the desired Workspace

Click Edit

Click Advanced

Then change the Owner

Comment: +10 for this one. The accepted answer may work for older versions of Visual Studio but this worked for Visual Studio 2015 as well. I did not even lose my changes; however, I would recommend backing those up anyway if you need to change your username.